# Log on as local account and access network drive as domain account after VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, domain

This question seems very similar, except we use a different VPN client: [Connect to domain account over VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/782203/connect-to-domain-account-over-vpn)

How can we log on as a local account, then VPN, and have *all* requests against a network drive authenticate as a domain account? Windows Explorer seems to work fine, but it seems like Internet Explorer (though the web application is implemented weird, so I don't know exactly what application is responsible) doesn't resolve the routing/authentication properly.

Is there a way to either switch the active account from a local one to a domain one after VPNing, or force applications to use the domain account for everything after logging on as a local account?

Comment: You can mount a network drive as any user you want.  You can either supply the current user, a different user (in the case of say a Drobo), or a users that exists on a AD domain.

Comment: @Ramhound if the share is not configured to bypass DNS, the network share may not be found because of it, and it does not matter what credentials you enter, you won't connect.